# How to disable button in another activity?

Tags: java, android

I have a game activity and when it ends it goes to main menu and now I need to disable the button which starts the game that just ended. Let's call my game class classGame and my menu classMenu. I tried:

in my classGame:

```
classMenu obj = new classMenu();
```

And then in the same class when the time is right I call:

```
obj.myButtonToBeDisabled.setEnabled(false);
```

But I get stactOverflow errors on line where I created my obj as soon my menu activity starts. How to do this?

EDIT:
I've also tried this in my gameClass:

```
public void disableButton(){
        button.setEnabled(false);
    }
```

and then calling it:

```
obj.disableButton
```

But the same error.

LogCat:

```
04-06 16:30:48.709: I/dalvikvm(25015): threadid=1: stack overflow on call to Ljava/lang/VMThread;.currentThread:L
04-06 16:30:48.709: I/dalvikvm(25015):   method requires 0+20+0=20 bytes, fp is 0x4214d300 (0 left)
04-06 16:30:48.709: I/dalvikvm(25015):   expanding stack end (0x4214d300 to 0x4214d000)
04-06 16:30:48.769: I/dalvikvm(25015): Shrank stack (to 0x4214d300, curFrame is 0x4214fcb0)
04-06 16:30:48.899: D/AndroidRuntime(25015): Shutting down VM
04-06 16:30:48.899: W/dalvikvm(25015): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018560)
04-06 16:30:49.369: D/dalvikvm(25015): GC_CONCURRENT freed 325K, 50% free 2850K/5639K, external 0K/0K, paused 5ms+24ms
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015): java.lang.StackOverflowError
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at java.lang.Thread.currentThread(Thread.)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:59)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at android.os.Looper.myLooper(Looper.)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at android.app.Activity.<init>(Activity.)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Izbor.<init>(Izbor.java:17)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Asocijacije.<init>(Asocijacije.java:32)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Izbor.<init>(Izbor.java:19)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Asocijacije.<init>(Asocijacije.java:32)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Izbor.<init>(Izbor.java:19)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Asocijacije.<init>(Asocijacije.java:32)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Izbor.<init>(Izbor.java:19)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Asocijacije.<init>(Asocijacije.java:32)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Izbor.<init>(Izbor.java:19)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Asocijacije.<init>(Asocijacije.java:32)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Izbor.<init>(Izbor.java:19)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Asocijacije.<init>(Asocijacije.java:32)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Izbor.<init>(Izbor.java:19)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Asocijacije.<init>(Asocijacije.java:32)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Izbor.<init>(Izbor.java:19)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Asocijacije.<init>(Asocijacije.java:32)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Izbor.<init>(Izbor.java:19)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Asocijacije.<init>(Asocijacije.java:32)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Izbor.<init>(Izbor.java:19)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Asocijacije.<init>(Asocijacije.java:32)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Izbor.<init>(Izbor.java:19)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Asocijacije.<init>(Asocijacije.java:32)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Izbor.<init>(Izbor.java:19)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Asocijacije.<init>(Asocijacije.java:32)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Izbor.<init>(Izbor.java:19)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Asocijacije.<init>(Asocijacije.java:32)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Izbor.<init>(Izbor.java:19)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Asocijacije.<init>(Asocijacije.java:32)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Izbor.<init>(Izbor.java:19)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Asocijacije.<init>(Asocijacije.java:32)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Izbor.<init>(Izbor.java:19)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Asocijacije.<init>(Asocijacije.java:32)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Izbor.<init>(Izbor.java:19)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Asocijacije.<init>(Asocijacije.java:32)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Izbor.<init>(Izbor.java:19)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Asocijacije.<init>(Asocijacije.java:32)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Izbor.<init>(Izbor.java:19)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Asocijacije.<init>(Asocijacije.java:32)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Izbor.<init>(Izbor.java:19)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Asocijacije.<init>(Asocijacije.java:32)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Izbor.<init>(Izbor.java:19)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Asocijacije.<init>(Asocijacije.java:32)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Izbor.<init>(Izbor.java:19)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Asocijacije.<init>(Asocijacije.java:32)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Izbor.<init>(Izbor.java:19)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Asocijacije.<init>(Asocijacije.java:32)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Izbor.<init>(Izbor.java:19)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Asocijacije.<init>(Asocijacije.java:32)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Izbor.<init>(Izbor.java:19)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Asocijacije.<init>(Asocijacije.java:32)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Izbor.<init>(Izbor.java:19)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.Asocijacije.<init>(Asocijacije.java:32)
04-06 16:30:49.459: E/AndroidRuntime(25015):    at rs.android
04-06 16:30:49.659: D/dalvikvm(25015): GC_CONCURRENT freed 522K, 51% free 2899K/5895K, external 0K/0K, paused 7ms+5ms
```

Asocijacije is my gameClass, and Izbor in my menuClass.

Comment: Can you disable the button *before* starting the game (i.e. as soon as it is clicked?). Either that or use startActivityForResult http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int) to get a callback when the activity ends?

Comment: Actually I don't really understand the error you are describing... If you have a stack overflow, look for a circular function call - i.e. function A calls function B which calls function A (A and B could be in different classes too).

Comment: If you want to just make it so that the user can't click on it and it doesn't appear, use `button.setVisible(false);`

Comment: No, I need it to be visible, I just need to be disabled. Even if I need what you said, it's the same method of doing like setEnabled(false); what I tried and get error, so I think I will get error with your code too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to call anything from within your game. If your menu is the one that started the game in the first place, it can get notified when the game's `Activity` has finished.

Start your game with `startActivityForResult` like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent ();
intent.setClassName ("com.your.package.name", "com.your.package.name.YourGameActivity");
startActivityForResult (intent, 0);
```

Then, in your game class, when your game finishes, call `setResult (int result)` before you `finish` your game `Activity` like this:

```
setResult (123);   // or something like Menu.GAME1_FINISHED
finish ();
```

Back in your Menu Activity, you have to implement the `onActivityResult` callback like this:

```
public void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult (requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    switch (resultCode)
    case 123:
        // hide button 1
    case 234:
        // hide button 2
    // etc...
}
```

Comment: Thank you good man! That worked. Can you take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754577/how-to-disable-interaction-between-buttons-of-the-same-layout)?

Comment: But how to disable a button in a Listview, @Shade ? Any information would be of great help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try `.setClickable(false)` instead, and take a look at this question I asked on the difference between them:

[setEnabled() vs setClickable(), what is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615823/setenabled-vs-setclickable-what-is-the-difference)

And without the error logs we can't help you more then this, please post them.

Comment: could you post your full class code, As I see it your errors are not derived from this action.

Comment: It pretty big class. Here you can see it in my github. Game class is Asocijacije.java and menu class is Izbor.java. The button i'm trying to disable is asocijacije. [link](https://github.com/Nabukodonosor/spojnice)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are having problems with a way to call the code to disable the button, a safe way to tell to the menu class to disable the button can be via LocalBroadcastManager, like described [here](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/Post/Using-LocalBroadcastManager-in-Service-to-Activity-Communications.aspx).

Basically you can register your menu object as listener of a especific broadcast message sent at the end of game which will execute the method to disable desired button.