# onClick not grasping the int increase within another onClick?

Tags: android, android-studio, onclick, android-button

So I have this code :

```
back --;    //when it starts doing that back's value is 5 

if (back == 0) {
    back_button.setClickable(false);    
}

if (back != 0) {
    back_button.setClickable(true);
}
```

My `back_button` never sets itself to `Clickable(true)` after it set to `Clickable(false)`, even when back wasn't equal to 0 caused by another `button(back++;)`.

Why isn't my `back_button` `onClick` realizing that?

Answer (score 0):

Actually view.setClickable() doesn't works at runtime that's why your toggling of back_button doesn't works at runtime .

**Solution:** Use view.setEnabled(boolean enabled) for your back_button.

Refer to :[setEnabled() vs setClickable(), what is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615823/setenabled-vs-setclickable-what-is-the-difference)